# How change value of variable in same class?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables

I'm new in python, and I have this code:

```
class Daemon():        
    db = Database()

    def __init__(self):        
        final_folder = ''
```

How I can change the value of the variable final_folder in the same class but in other function?

I try the code like below but isn't work:

```
class Daemon():    
    db = Database()

    def __init__(self):
        final_folder = ''

    def get_mail_body(self, msg):
        Daemon.final_folder = 'someotherstring'
```

Comment: `final_folder` is a *local variable* that ceases to exist once `__init__` is done executing. You likely want to use an *instance variable*, in which case, you need to explicitely use `self.final_folder = ''` then access it with `self.final_folder` in other methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to it as `self.final_folder` in `__init__`, like:

```
class Daemon():

    db = Database()

    def __init__(self):

        self.final_folder = ''

    def get_mail_body(self, msg):

        self.final_folder = 'someotherstring'
```

Then you should be able to do something like:

```
my_daemon = Daemon()
print(my_daemon.final_folder)
# outputs: ''
my_daemon.get_mail_body('fake message')
print(my_daemon.final_folder)
# outputs: 'someotherstring'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the variable with self if you are using inside the class. self holds the current object.

Here is the updated code.

```
def __init__(self):
   self.final_folder = ''
def get_mail_body(self)
    self.final_folder = 'Hello'
```

Create the object of the class and access the variable.

Comment: I need to change value of the final_folder, if the function is within the class it doesn't change the value

Comment: Is this not the same solution that I posted? If you think it's different, can you edit clarify the difference / improvement?